# Facebook logout does not work for dev, beta and www at the same time

Tags: javascript, facebook, oauth, oauth-2.0, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have already gone through questions posted on SF for this. No concrete answer though.

My web application is running on three environements dev, beta and production.
When facebook login has dev configured in the settings like this logout works:
[image]

But it does not work when my website is running on beta or www. Even after making it as `https://foo.com` or `https://*.foo.com` it does not work. This site url setting also does not allow mutliple urls. I can see following issue in the console when I try to logout from `beta.foo.com` or `www.foo.com`.
[image]

This is how logout funtion handles facebook logout:

```
onLogoutClick() {
    if (this.state.loggedInUser.Type === Constants.FACEBOOK) { 
      FB.logout((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        console.log('Facebook user has been logged out.');
        this.handleLogout();
      },
        (error) => console.log(error));
    }
}
```

Does anybody know how to make it work for all the environments?

Comment: _“But it does not work when my website is running on beta or www”_ - by that you mean `beta.foo.com` or `www.foo.com`? Then just input `https://foo.com` as the website address - subdomains are automatically covered.

Comment: Yes. Even after making it as `https://foo.com` it does not work. Now it does not work for any of the environment.

Comment: How exactly are you triggering logout?

Comment: @CBroe: Please see the edited question.